# Css marquee text stack below to each other when use ngFor

Tags: css, angular, sass

Trying to create marquee using CSS, i manage to make it work but not what I'm expected.
When I'm using ngFor to provide the data.

this is the result that i got

[image]

Text goes under each other and now I'm stuck, i don't know how to fix.

this is working link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzstvh

This is my HTML

```
<div class="message-alert ">
<div  class="container pr-0 pl-0 marquee" >
      <div>
          <a *ngFor="let text of messages">
                    {{text}}
          </a>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is SCSS

```
.message-alert {
  border-style: solid ;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: $light_gray;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-top: 15px;

  &:hover{
    .marquee div {
      display: block;
      width: 200%;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation-play-state:paused;
    }
  }

  .marquee {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  .marquee div {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
  }

  .marquee a{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  @keyframes marquee {
    0% {
      left: 100%;
    } 

    95% {
      left: -100%;
    }

    100% {
      left: -100%;
    }
  }
}
```

text should move to the left and not goes under each other.
I'm sorry my English is not good.

Comment: can you please add a working link.. i cannot replicate it. thanks

Comment: create a stackblitz so others can easily replicate it

Comment: Sorry guys. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzstvh 
i'm using scss so it doesn't work. Can i change css to scss some how on stackblitz? @SadidKhan

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzstvh here

Comment: @XenioGracias

stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzstvh

Answer (score 0):

Сan be used the marquee tag in HTML: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzavqc

Comment: Marquee tag is not as good as CSS animation tho. You can see the different. 
Marquee is laggy but not the CSS.
Anyway can you help me solve the problem with CSS?